# Multiple event occur when hovering anchor within span

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make color over the image on hover, also I want the delete icon to appear over the image, the problem I face is that when mouse is over the delete icon, many events occur continually.

here is the HTML

```
 <span class="imageContent" >
  <a  class="imgOverlay" href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yAOYE3-J1mo/TmsnBJ6ucYI/AAAAAAAABcA/5ZKqEv3p-6I/s1600/36676-sky_blue.jpg" target="_blank" >
       <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yAOYE3-J1mo/TmsnBJ6ucYI/AAAAAAAABcA/5ZKqEv3p-6I/s1600/36676-sky_blue.jpg" />
   </a>
    <a href="" name="deleteImg" class="delete">delete</a>
 </span>
```

and here is the js

```
 $(".imgOverlay > img").hover(function(e){

    $(this).fadeTo("fast",0.3);
    $('.delete').css('display','inline-block');
},function(e){

    $(this).fadeTo("fast",1.0);
    $('.delete').css('display','none');
});

$(".imgOverlay > .delete").hover(function(e){


    $('.delete').css('display','inline-block');
},function(e){ 
    $('.delete').css('display','none');
});


$('.imgOverlay .delete').click(function(e){
  alert('click');
});
```

Here is a live example
http://jsbin.com/asehuq/1/edit

Comment: what's the use of the hover in delete, when it is already showing when you hover it on the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(".delete").hover(function (e) {
  //e.stopPropagation(); <----this is not required because your element is not 
  //                          the child of the ".imgOverlay"
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.delete').css('display', 'inline-block');
}, function (e) {
  $('.delete').css('display', 'none');
});


$('.delete').click(function (e) {
  alert('click');
});
```

Infact you are binding the event to both items that caused the issue.

What i mean is see this:

```
$(".imgOverlay > .delete").hover(function(e){
```

according to your markup `.delete` is not the direct children of `.imOverlay`.

here:

```
$('.imgOverlay .delete').click(function(e){
```

you are binding the click event to both the elements which is not required.

Comment: Wow it works, then this selector $(".imgOverlay > .delete") doesn't mean to select .delete only!! it select it's parent too

Comment: Well `.imgOverlay` is not the parent it is sibling to `.delete` and both of these do have a parent `.imageContent`

Comment: if this satisfies your needs then you can accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try those:

- use mouseenter and mouseleave instead of hover.
- call stop before performing any animation

  $(this).stop(true).fadeTo("fast",0.3);

Answer (score 0):

You can control the display of `.delete` with css instead of javascript:

```
.imageContent:hover .delete {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then use this for your javascript:

```
$('.imageContent').hover(function(e){
    $(this).find('img').fadeTo("fast",0.3);
},function(e){
    $(this).find('img').fadeTo("fast",1.0);
});

$('.imageContent .delete').click(function(e){
    alert('click');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/asehuq/5/edit)**